# Prestashop 1.6 url virtual products

Tags: prestashop

Is it possible to have virtual products online see in prestasho ? I do not want that downloading is allowed, just want it to look online

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop have Catalog option for disable buying options. Just for product presentation without Add To Cart functionality etc. Product will be available. You can also disable price if You want in Catalog mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common, several shops want to be available online only for information and marketing purposes, but don't want to sell online.

Here you have some resources for learn how to activate "Catalog Mode" in PrestaShop 1.6.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/catalog-mode

This tutorial will help:  http://cart-help.com/topic/129-hide-prices-disable-cart-catalog-mode-in-prestashop-16/

Also if you want to show prices in catalog mode:

http://customprestshoptemplates.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/how-to-display-price-on-prestashop.html

Regards